# How to calculate top co-ordinates of a rectangle given the bottom ones using opncv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to draw a rectangle on a certain area of the face of which I have lower 2 co-ordinates (left and right).

Now I am trying to calculate the top 2 co-ordinates that would complete a rectangle. I have height as int value that I want to add.

How do I add this height to 2 bottom points?
Say:

```
bottom_left = (x1, y1)
botoom_right = (x2, y2)
```

And I want to add 60 as heigh to both point above. So how do I calculate:

```
top_left = ?
top_right = ?
```

so that I can use:

```
cv2.rectangle(face, (bottom_left, top_left), (top_right, bottom_right), (255, 0, 0), 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that the rectangle is not (necessarily) axis aligned (that is, y1 != y2)?

Comment: @DrewHall bottom co-ordinates are 2 eyes if that makes you understand better. And I need a height of 60 from both eyes.

Comment: If I understand your question, top_left=bottom_left-60; top_right=bottom_right-60.

Comment: rectangle function does not draw a rotated rectangle. Be aware of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following:

```
h = 60
deltaX = x2 - x1
deltaY = y2 - y1
w = math.sqrt(deltaX**2 + deltaY**2)

dxHat = -deltaY / w
dyHat = deltaX / w

dx = h * dxHat
dy = h * dyHat

top_left = (x1 + dx, y1 + dy)
top_right = (x2 + dx, y2 + dy)
```

This version corrects for the skewness of my previous (incorrect) trig-based solution by using the 2D perp operation explicitly (in the computation of dxHat and dyHat).  It then scales by the desired h to compute the offsets from the original points.

Comment: thanks your code helped to go forward. However, it's only giving me the 2 points **below** which I want them on top instead. I have added an image for ref, blue and green are points that I got which I need above.

Comment: Try y1-dy and y2-dy.  I forgot that the y axis goes from the top down, not bottom up.  Glad it helped you some anyway!